# Angular Post request with response access response.body issue

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I'm sending a POST request to my server and I need to access the response.body.

Unfortunately, I'm not finding a method of doing that

**The POST request**

```
bday(id: number) {
let params = this.userParams;
return this.http
  .post<User[]>(environment.apiUrl + 'user/bday/' + id, {
    observe: 'response',
    params,
  })
  .pipe(
    map((response) => {
// I need to access the response.body
        })
      );
  }
```

But I'm getting the error: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'User[]' no matter what I'm trying.

I tried to declare the value response as HttpResponse<User[]> but that didn't work either.

I'm wondering why I'm not able to access the body of the response ?

I did a Get request and everything went smooth:

**Get request**

```
getUseres(params) {
return this.http
  .get<User[]>(environment.apiUrl + 'users', {
    observe: 'response',
    params,
  })
  .pipe(
    map((response) => {
      this.paginatedResult.result = response.body;
      if (response.headers.get('Pagination') != null) {
        this.paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(
          response.headers.get('Pagination')
        );
      }
      return this.paginatedResult;
    })
  );
```

}

Does anyone had that issue before and know how to fix it ?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Why do you want to access the request body? You’re receiving JSON, right? Angular is already deserialising it’s for you. If you don’t want that then you should use a different function on Angular’s `HttpClient`.

Comment: can you show your response that you get from API when using POST method?

Comment: when you console.log(response) what do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

The post method signature is `post(url, body, options)`

So its probably not working because your setting your options as the second argument instead of the third one.

cheers